# Sampling n values for each element

Tags: r

If I have the following data:

```
user_id <- seq_len(5)
product_id <- sample(0:1000,100,rep=TRUE)
```

and want to randomly join `n` products from `product_id` to each `user_id`, how can this be done without a loop?

- multiple user can have the same product
- a user can have duplicate products

I've tried this (`n = 3`):

```
data <- cbind(user_id[1], sample(product_id, 3))
for (i in 2:length(user_id)) {
  data <- rbind(data, cbind(user_id[i], sample(product_id, 3)))
}
```

and while it produces the desired result, it is way too slow.

```
      [,1] [,2]
 [1,]    1  102
 [2,]    1   27
 [3,]    1  740
 [4,]    2   27
 [5,]    2  770
 [6,]    2  570
 [7,]    3  662
 [8,]    3   75
 [9,]    3  886
[10,]    4  984
[11,]    4  411
[12,]    4  297
[13,]    5  950
[14,]    5   37
[15,]    5   17
```

Comment: Multiple users can have the same product?

Comment: You don't need a loop. Something like `setNames(sample(product_id, length(user_id)*3, replace = TRUE), rep(user_id, each = 3))` will work

Comment: @Sotos Minor point: a single call to `sample` (with default replace = FALSE) cannot produce what they show (product 27 for both users 1 & 2).

Comment: Good eye @Frank. Did not even notice that

Comment: Yes, the multiple user can have the same product

Comment: Can one `user_id` have 2 same `product_ids`?

Comment: Yes, a user can have duplicate products

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one idea using `setNames` to attach the IDs in our `sample`, i.e.

```
n=3
setNames(sample(product_id, length(user_id)*n, replace = TRUE), 
         rep(user_id, each = n))

#  1   1   1   2   2   2   3   3   3   4   4   4   5   5   5 
#388 459 714 251 990 419 469 817  78 428 338 143 398 299 398
```

Comment: Any reason for the `setNames` approach and not a simple `cbind`? `cbind(rep(user_id, each = 3), sample(product_id, length(user_id)*3, TRUE))`?

Comment: Well hello...long time no see :) ... No reason, just didn't come to mind